# Hysterisis in rubber bands

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Intuitively, why do rubber bands, when stretched, show Hysteresis? I'm hoping for an interesting thought experiment to prove this, rather than usual mathematical descriptions.

Comment: Do rubber bands show hysteresis? I've never noticed that.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Somebody I know tried to do some research based on https://www.vernier.com/innovate/elastic-hysteresis-of-a-rubber-band/ but he had conceptual trouble.

Comment: It looks like the 7-inch rubber band was extended by over 11 inches (30 cm). That's an over 100% strain. Not surprised that a rubber band stretched by so much might show some irreversibility or hysteresis, possibly due to small local damage in the rubber or maybe polymer chains settling into different positions with respect to each other after experiencing very large strain and relaxation.

Comment: So hysteresis is irreversibility in shape change? I'm not very clear about it...

Comment: Hysteresis here is associated with some dependence on the strain history of the material. If the amount of strain was indeed over 100%, I wouldn't be surprised that there might be micro-scale damage or adjustments to the polymer chains which would cause the force exerted by the rubber band to change even when it is stretched by the same amount.

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Elastic_hysteresis